# How to solve this Class f com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i am getting this error when i am build my flutter project. also when i am try to debug it also it failed to debug app. can anyone help me to getting out of this.Hope you understanf the question. your help will be appericiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Simply Add this two dependency to your pubspec.yml. this works for me.

```
firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1 
firebase_core: ^0.3.0
```

Comment: Enjoy Coding :)